# Как включить в страницу темплейт JS кода, чтобы он НЕ исполнялся?

Tags: javascript, html5, шаблоны, синтаксис

Так включают фрагмент HTML, который потом вытаскивают скриптом, а при загрузке страницы он никак себя не проявляет:

```
<script id="tmpl-hello" type="text/template">
    <h1>Привет, %username%!</h1>
</script>
```

Какие ещё значения `type` можно указывать для использования подобной техники?

Хочу вставить темплейт JS-подобного кода, при "text/template" в IDE подсветка кода считает, что это HTML. Неаккуратненько как-то.. : )

Answer (score 1):

Если я вас правильно понял, то попробуйте использовать **[Shadow DOM](http://habrahabr.ru/post/180377/)**

В статье на хабре как раз приводится пример с использованием template'ов.